# Managing multiple HTTP requests in Android

Tags: android, asynchronous, httprequest

I want my app to get all the media on my phone, then send the actual data to my server.

I got all the absolute paths of the media on the phone, now I want the manage the requests. Is there a way to make some sort of request array, that will run until it's empty?

If so can I upgrade it into priority array? For example, someone uploads 100MB of media, I want them to continue browsing my app, and if they makes an action, that specific action will enter that request array poll, but with high priority? As if the next request that I will send is the one I’ve just created?

I also need it to be crash proof, if my app crashes I will still know where I stopped and continue from there and not from the beginning.

I know that’s a lot of requirements, but im not experienced enough to know if its even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my research went this was my solution to it.

Create  a callable class named `myThread` which will handle the request itself, and will delete and change the statuses of the request on our SQLite DB.

```
public class MyThread implements Callable {

private File _file;
private Context context;
private DBHelper helper;

public MyThread(File file, Context context) {
    this._file = file;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public String call() throws Exception {
    HttpClient client = Utility.getNewHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.9.62/mobile_api/timeline/moment/upload");
    try {
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(_file);
        builder.addPart("content", fileBody);
        builder.addPart("type", new StringBody("file", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("title", new StringBody("service test", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("userType", new StringBody("user", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("uid", new StringBody(MyInfiActivity.friends_uid, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("momentId", new StringBody("1", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("storyId", new StringBody("8", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        Utility.addCookiesToPost(post);

        post.setEntity(builder.build());
        client.execute(post, localContext);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Callable try", post.toString());

    }
    return "1";
}
```

An `IntentService` that creates 5 threads (for better performances... Not sure about how good it is) where each thread gets `MyThread` callable to know which entry to delete on the DB upon finishing.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    helper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    File file;
    Log.e("requestsExists",helper.requestsExists()+"");
    while(helper.requestsExists()){
        ArrayList<String> requestArr = helper.getRequestsToExcute(5);
        //checks if the DB requests exists
        if(!requestArr.isEmpty()){
            //execute them and delete the DB entry
            for(int i=0;i<requestArr.size();i++){
                file = new File(requestArr.get(i));

                Log.e("file",file.toString());
                Future<String> future = executor.submit(new MyThread(file,getApplicationContext()));

                Log.e("future object", future.toString());
                try {
                    long idToDelete = Long.parseLong(future.get());
                    Log.e("THREAD ANSWER", future.get() + "");
                    helper.deleteRequest(idToDelete);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e("future try", "");
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

NOTE: the data is hard coded for testing, will contain variables according to the media I will send